# tensorflow | GpuLauchKernel() no kernel image is avaliable on the device

Tags: tensorflow

I download a program from Github and try to run it on my laptop. I've checked my GPU's computeCapability is 5.0. And I don't know how to solve this. I installed CUDA 10.1 and cudnn 8.0, is this the problem?

`2020-08-13 16:03:07.860157: F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_2d_gpu.h:504] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(ShuffleInTensor3Simple<T, 2, 1, 0>, config.block_count, config.thread_per_block, 0, d.stream(), config.virtual_thread_count, in.data(), combined_dims, out.data()) status: Internal: no kernel image is available for execution on the device`

Comment: The version of the software you are using clearly has not been compiled with support for your GPU. The solution would be to get or compile a version which includes the required support

Comment: which software?

Comment: Whatever the "program from Github" is. Tensorflow or some extension of Tensorflow?

Comment: It's a LeNet code.  It uses Tensorflow. I installed tf 2.3.0.

Comment: So one of those hasn't been built with support for Maxwell GPUs

Comment: read hardware requirements [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) especially the note in blue with the star.Your TF version was built without support for compute capability 5.0.

Comment: I've checked CUDA-Enabled Geforce products, and my GPU is GeForce 960M. hardware requirements says that compute capability should be higher than 3.5.